# Angular 4 Using public static readonly strings in ngIf

Tags: angular

I have a class called `UserRoles`, defined as such :

```
export class UserRoles
{
    public static readonly MODERATOR  = "moderator";
    public static readonly SPONSOR    = "sponsor";
    public static readonly BASE_USER  = "user";
}
```

I have a Component, called `MenuComponent`, such that in the .ts file, I `import { UserRoles } from "../../../models/userRoles";`, and in the .html file for that component, I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul *ngIf="currentUser.role == UserRoles.BASE_USER" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- NOTE: whatever routerLinks you create here need to be added and handled properly in routing.ts -->
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="leaderboard">Leaderboard</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="feed">Feed</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="score">Score</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="my-posts">My Posts</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="create-posts">Create Posts</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="edit-posts">Edit Posts</button></li>
        </ul>
        <ul *ngIf="currentUser.role == UserRoles.MODERATOR" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- NOTE: whatever routerLinks you create here need to be added and handled properly in routing.ts -->
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="flagged-users">Flagged Users</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="flagged-posts">Flagged Posts</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="flagged-comments">Flagged Comments</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="my-messages">My Messages</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="create-messages">Create Messages</button></li>
        </ul>
        <ul *ngIf="currentUser.role == UserRoles.SPONSOR" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- NOTE: whatever routerLinks you create here need to be added and handled properly in routing.ts -->
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="balance">Balance</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="popular-users">Popular Users</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="my-advertisements">My Advertisements</button></li>
            <li><button class="menuButton" routerLink="create-advertisements">Create Advertisements</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I fire up the `ng serve` and test this out, none of the above renders, and when I check Developer Console, I am greeted with message that basically tells me that `UserRoles` is not defined.

Is there anything that I should be doing with that `UserRoles` class, either here or in `app.module.ts`?

Answer (score 6):

The expressions in the template expect to use variables and methods of the component class. In order to access the values of `UserRoles` in the template, you can assign that class to a member variable of the component class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserRoles } from "./user-roles.model";

@Component(
    ...
)
export class UserComponent {
    public UserRolesClass = UserRoles;
    ....
}
```

and use that variable in the template:

```
<ul *ngIf="currentUser.role == UserRolesClass.BASE_USER" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

The technique is shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqvv4g).